# How to generate Class Diagram (UML) on Android Studio (IntelliJ Idea)

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, class-diagram

I've try to search and found this [**link**](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/uml_designer.html), but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> doesn't work.

I also use find Action <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to find action about diagram and uml but found nothing.

I also [**search for the uml plugin**](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/search/index?pr=idea&search=uml),
but most of them didn't work with new version of intelliJ (I didn't try it I just read the comment).

Comment: I noticed the UML Modeling feature only available in Ultimate Edition but not in Community Edition see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I found a free plugin that can generate class diagrams with android studio.
It's called **SimpleUML**.

**Update Android Studio 2.2+:**
To install the plugin, follow steps in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36823007/1245894

**Older version of Android Studio**
On Mac: go to `Android Studio` -> `Preferences` -> `Plugins`

On Windows: go to `Android Studio` -> `File` -> `Settings` -> `Plugins`

Click on `Browse repositories...` and search for **SimpleUMLCE** 
(CE means Community Edition, this is what android studio is based on).

Install it, restart, then you can do a right click on the folder containing the classes you want to visualize, and select `Add to simpleUML Diagram`.

That's it; you have you fancy class diagram generated from your code!

Comment: I can't find SimpleUMLCE in the repositories, has it been removed?

Comment: And hasn't been updated in almost 6 years - looks dead.

Comment: I right clicked on the folder containing classes I wanted to visualize, selected `Add to simpleUML Diagram` ... and an empty diagram appeared. Impressive.

Comment: doesn't work anymore, should edit answer to provide solution for AS 2.x

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but I got this error<Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction())
         Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6,4,main] 10153571
         ; dispatch thread: false; isDispatchThread(): false
         SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 IDEA 15.0.5#IC-143.2332.3 IDEA, eap:false, os:Windows 8 6.2, java-version:Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_51-b16,6,main] 4127389>

Comment: Android Studio 2.2.2 users don't bother, this repository isn't exists in our IDE, you can refer to this answer as obsolete.

Comment: @Eido95 as mentionned by farhangdon , you can still manually download and install the plugin which still works with 2.2.2

Comment: **SimpleUMLCE** doesn't exist in repository browser.

Comment: if you want this to work on Kotlin too all you need to do is `show kotlin bytecode` and decompile it to `java` and then add to diagram

Comment: It showed up fine in Android Studio's Plugin Marketplace and worked for me.

Comment: This is not supported by AS anymore!

Comment: @Cory Roy Maybe if you still use Android Studio from the middle Ages...

Comment: My Android Studio version is the latest, however it says plugin is marked as incompatible to this version

Comment: Perhaps I'm coming late, but I made it by installing PlantUML Integration: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration

Answer (score 95):

**For those who want to use simpleUML in Android Studio and having issues in running SimpleUML.**

First download simpleUML jar from here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4946-simpleumlce

Now follow the below steps.

**Step 1:**

Click on **File** and go to **Settings**  ***(File → Settings)***

**Step 2**

 Select **Plugins** from Left Panel and click **Install plugin from disk**

[image: 1]]

**Step 3:** 
 
Locate the **SimpleUML jar** file and select it.

[image: 2]]

**Step 4:**

**Now Restart Android Studio (File → Invalidate Caches/Restart → Just Restart)**

**Step 5:**

After you restart **Right Click the Package name**  and Select **New Diagram** or **Add to simpleUML Diagram → New Diagram**.

[image: 3]

**Step 6:**

Set a file name and create UML file. **I created with name NewDiagram**

[image]
**Step 7:**

Now **Right Click the Package name**  and Select the file you created. In my case it was **NewDiagram**

[image]

**Step 8:**

All files are stacked on top of one another. You can just drag and drop them and set a hierarchy.

[image]

**Like this below, you can drag these classes**

[image]

Comment: is there some way of auto arranging 200++ stacked classes?!

Comment: Unfortunately no, I also did individually.

Comment: Actually I just found it. There is grayed icon, second from the bottom in second column of icons, that does auto-layout and it is not disabled as it looks. "Toggle-Automatic-Layout".

Comment: That's great, I will check it, and will update in answer.

Comment: @farhangdon Please confirm the Sequence diagram, Package Diagram and DependenciesDiagram generates empty objects and you have to do t manually - unless if there is something I am missing

Comment: @farhangdon Please confirm the Sequence diagram, Package Diagram and DependenciesDiagram generates empty objects and you have to do t manually - unless if there is something I am missing

Comment: FYI I had to import twice (AS 2.3), the first time AS (Android Studio) didn't restart, it just closed (shut down). I gave it another try (ran through the import steps above) and everything worked.

Comment: @JamesNelson m glad it worked for you, first time there might be some issue with android studio as its quite slow and often lags. For me it worked in the very first time.

Comment: How to save this class diagram ?

Comment: Well, you can just use the snipping tool of windows so save each page.

Comment: Just finished complete set of diagrams with SimpleUML just to find out that print fuction is printing text (xml) not image of diagram and export not working. Only way to use those diagrams in documentation is to screenshot .... Skip this tool

Comment: Do you have any recommendation in version 3.1?

Comment: As of March 2019, can confirm that this still works.

Comment: @chowden how were you able to actually see anything? My UI display is empty.

Comment: Class diagram generation works as of June 2019. Using AS 3.4.1. 

This is great.

Comment: Ok, its working great but it omits long class members/methods names which makes it hard to guess their names. Is there any way to fix the 3-dots at the end of members/methods names?

Comment: Hi @blueware unfortunately NO, there are certain limitation and I believe this is one of them, if you find some way also update me Thanks

Comment: Hi @farhangdon, I found a solution. Its to install **IntelliJ Ultimate** edition and use its superior `UML Class Diagram` buy selecting a class/package then right click and choose the option `UML Class Diagram` and trigger related buttons to see your classes with their dependencies, parents and relations. Thanks to **IntelliJ** for that. Also consider buying a license for it if you want to continue using it.

Comment: fyi: As of Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1, I am unable to install the specified *.jar. There are unfortunately compatibility issues.

Comment: @CoachRoebuck, me the same. It indicates that the versions are explicitly incompatible. :?

Answer (score 26):

I have managed to to do it in a way. Perform all the steps as referenced by Michal Rowicki above.

1. Open Visual Paradigm software.
2. Create a new Project
3. There would be an option on the `Tools` bar above that states `Code`
   and select `Instant Reverse...` from the drop down menu with Java
   language(or other)
4. Select your application folder where your project is located and
   add it to the project(i have selected the complete folder
   application)
5. The application should now appear on the left pane in Class
   Repository
6. Then all you do is right click the project that you have added and
   select Reverse to new class diagram
7. Select either you wish to have the packages included in the class
   diagram or just the class diagram of the project

Then it should appear on your screen and customize it as you wish

However i do not know if the plugin in Android Studio was necessary nevertheless it has worked in a way for me.

Comment: Tried this without mentioned plugin and it is working. No need to install it.

Comment: After step 7 nothing happen

Comment: @Matteo you have to wait a little bit, the window with your class diagram should appear in a few seconds (maybe a minute) not directly, maybe it depends on how fast your computer is.

Answer (score 19):

1. type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or go to Preferences)
2. go to the Plugins tab, press "Browse repositories" button
3. search:
    `Visual Paradigm SDE for IntellIJ (Community edition) Modelling Case Tool`
4. install it.

You need to install [proper software](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/features/). Now it should works well.

I guess that UML Class Diagram is only available on Ultimate Edition.

To show UML diagram click right mouse button on specific class -> Diagrams -> Show diagram...
Or you can in editor click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.
You could append new classes to diagram by drag and drop. On the top of window you could choose more options. To save UML you should just click on save icon.

Comment: I have already added it. But I don't know how to use it. I also try to search with many keyword eg.visual paradigm sde for intellij example,how to use,user manual etc.

Comment: I just try to download Visual Paradigm SDE (Community edition) but cannot integrated to Android Studio because not an IntelliJ support version

Comment: i dl'ed this: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?pr=&updateId=1149 and this: http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/vpuml.jsp?edition=ce .. but, how we use it?

Comment: @MichalRowicki  So how do you use Visual Paradigm in Android Studio after you install it?

Comment: So is there no support for UML diagrams for Studio yet?

Comment: I installed the plug in android studio but how can I generate UML diagram for my code.

Comment: It states that this feature is only available in the `Standard edition` and above. Thus they contradict themselves from their own feature page... What a rip-off!

Comment: At the moment being, my the plugin is 10 year old. I hardly beleive it works: http://snag.gy/vIuQG.jpg

Answer (score 19):

There is [Code Iris](http://www.codeiris.com/) which you can install by going to File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories, then find and choose Code Iris.
Restart then you will have a new Code Iris tab.

Comment: Nice solution! I will play with your solution to make sure this is the best solution.

Comment: after installing it one can not use Android Studio anymore.. :S

Comment: @w3officefb It generates the connections click 'Create/Update Diagram' and select one of the 3 views.

Comment: @Ewoks I am using Android Studio 2.1 and it seems to work fine for me :/

Comment: AS 3.5 not opening after installing the plugin.

Answer (score 15):

### Update 24.3.2016

I have found this guide from VP https://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/technical-support/running-vp-in-android-studio/ created on September 8, 2015.

Good to know - it is possible to integrate VP into Android studio (in my case **1.5.1**) now. Do not forget to **backup** your Android Studio **settings** (you can find them in Users%userName/.AndroidStudioX.X on Windows) ahead of installation.

I was trying to make it work, but created vp project did not contain any diagrams. Maybe someone else will have more luck.

---

I was using this manual http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/2381/2385/66578_creatingauml.html to make Visual Paradigm working in Android studio, but action in 2. did not invoke dialogue in 3. So I Have asked **Visual Paradigm support** for help and they replied that **Android Studio** integration **is not supported** right now.

Reply from Visual paradigm reply from Apr 17 2015:

> Thank you for your inquiry and I'm very sorry that at the moment **we
>   only support** integrate with the **standard IntelliJ IDEA**, but
>   **not** integrate with the **Android Studio**. We may consider to support it in our future release, and I'll keep you post once there
>   any update on this topics. Feel free to contact me for any questions
>   and wish you have a good day!

This post was deleted, so I will try to make it more clear.

As such I am considering **previous** answers as **misleading** and not useful. Therefore I thing that it is important for others to know that, before they lose their time trying to make it working.

Comment: thanks I've already lost my time trying make it work, so do you know of any other alternative, since almost everywere they point you to the missleading option   visual Paradigm  plugin

Comment: Hi Pedro, for now - I do not know any solution I have tried some UML solutions but none that I like. We probably should wait for VP till they implement it or somebody else come's up with something useful. Please if you thing this answer is right and others not - up vote it. It helps others not to go through this time waist full experience. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

**Solution:**

1. Run Visual Paradigm
2. Do as below, pointing to Android Atudio
   directory on step 4

[image]

3. Open Android Studio and right click on project

[image]

Comment: great - what's the next step?

Comment: nurne did you understand whats the next step?

Answer (score 2):

This Kotlin state machine library has PlantUML export feature, it is not integrated with Android Studio but it is easy to visualize state machine structure on PlantUML web site.

https://github.com/nsk90/kstatemachine

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing with android studio 2+.

to create class diagrams I did the following: 
- install "ObjectAid UML Explorer" as plugin for eclipse(in my case luna with android sdk but works with younger versions as well)
... go to eclipse marketplace and search for "ObjectAid UML Explorer". 
it's further down in the search results.
after installation and restart of eclipse ...

open an empty android or what-ever-java-project in eclipse. 
then right click on the empty eclipse project in the project explorer 
-> select 'build path'
then I link my ANDROID STUDIO SRC PATH into my eclipse android project. 
doesn't matter if there are errors. 
again right click on the eclipse-android project and select: New 
in the filter type 'class' 
then you should see among others an option 'class diagram'
... select it and confgure it ... png stuff, visibility, etc. 
drag/drop your ANDROID STUDIO project classes into the open diagram -> voila :)

hth

I open eclipse(luna, but that doesn't matter). 
I got the "ObjectAid UML Explorer"
that installed I open an empty android project oin eclipse, right

Comment: oops sorry, last two lines are mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple program [StarUML](http://staruml.io/). The trial version is unlimited and can do almost anything.

Onced installed you can use it to generate great number of uml digrams just by pasting the source code. Class diagram is just one type of it. (It understands not only Java language but C#, C++ and other)

P.S. The program is great for drawing architectural diagrams  before you start to code the program.

Comment: But you have to use it outside of Android Studio. It's manual creation. By the time you finish creating a class module, it would have been changed in the code. The better solutions auto generate these graphs.