# How to generate and work with UML diagrams in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, diagram

Are there any features in Android Studio for showing different diagrams such as: class diagrams, sequence diagrams and others?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio

Comment: **YES HERE:**

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio/29475203#29475203

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains does not put this feature in community edition IDEs