# Is there an android studio plugin that convert code to UML diagrams

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I downloaded an android studio project and I wanted to convert that code into UML diagrams to understand the engineering of code,so I need a tool or a plugin that will reverse it into UML diagrams.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate Class Diagram (UML) on android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio)