# Generating UML diagram in Android Studio

Tags: android, uml

[image: Android Studio]What is the best tool for generating UML diagrams from Java source files in Android Studio? Are there any plugins similar to *ObjectAid* in Android Studio.

There is no Visual Paradigm EE shown as described http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/2381/2385/66578_creatingauml.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate Class Diagram (UML) on android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio)

Comment: # **SOLUTION HERE:** #

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio/29475203#29475203

Comment: I think this can help you. It helped for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try **Code Iris**. You can install it in **Android Studio** as a plugin.

Open Android Studio Settings: File -> Settings. Look for Plugins, then hit "Browse repositories..." and type "Code Iris". Install and restart your IDE.

There is another plugin that could be interesting too, which is **PlantUML**. You may need to install **[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)** in order to make it work.

- **Code Iris** allows to export your diagram into a **json** file.
- **PlantUML** allows to save your diagram as a **PNG** file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Code Iris 2.0-Beta does not work for me on MacOS 10.11 with Android Studio 2.3.

Comment: Code iris 1.11-beta works with Android studio 2.3.1 . Mac OS 10.12.3

Comment: @JamesBond I was able to get it working by doing the Homebrew install.

Comment: Code Iris doesn't generate proper class diagrams. It produces diagrams, but they aren't class diagrams

Answer (score 7):

Two things you need to understand.

1. You need to first install VP **and** then the plugin, for this to work.
2. VP is [tricking you](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/editions/community.jsp) to think it's available in the CE edition, when in
   fact it is not. They state at some point that this feature is
   **only available** for the `Standard Edition` and above. So the name of
   the plugin is tricking you into this. Thus you're limited to a 30
   day trial.

They say:

> ...Visual Paradigm Community Edition supports running inside Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ and Visual Studio. Without leaving your IDE, you can review your software design described in UML.

**To install the plug-in:**

The proper path to go is from the `File` item, go to `Settings`. Then in the new settings window, scroll down (left side) to `Plugins`. Click on it and the Plugins menu (sub-window) will open. At the bottom of that there is a button called `Browse repositories...`. Click on it, and there will be yet another window (phuh!) with a very long list of plugins. There are hundreds, so use the search bar in that window and type "Visual Paradigm", this will give you only one choice, the `"Visual Paradigm SDE for IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition)"`. Click on it and then again on the right side, on the green button that says `Install plugin`. Accept the install and then restart AS.

**To use the native windows app:**

To create an UML from reversing the Java code in VP, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25727280/1147688) post.

Comment: I had followed the above steps but couldnot find any method to create a uml diagram of the project inside AS.
Can you describe me what can i do after i restart AS?? Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a good question. Since I don't have that edition, it never shows up in my AS either, but I can create diagrams in VP. So I can only conclude it's some kind of marketing trick by VP.

Comment: Visual Paradigm community edition won't allow you to generate a diagram from existing Java code, which is what many of us want to get.

Answer (score 0):

For creating UML class diagram in android studio use the following steps :
Press Ctrl+Alt+S (or go to Settings), then go to the Plugins tab, press "Browse repositories" button then search "Visual Paradigm SDE for intelliJ" install this plugin into Android Studio and restart the IDE.

After successfully install the above plugin follow the step which are listed on following URL:
http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/2381/2385/66578_creatingauml.html

Comment: I have already done that.. there is no option related to Visual Paradigm EE in the options.