# Tool to generate visual diagrams from Android code

Tags: android

I want to upgrade/modify an existing Android app code base and it is pretty huge to understand its implementation in quick time. So, I was trying to figure out if there are tools which could help accomplish my job faster in terms of UML, sequence, block diagrams, etc.

I am aware of such tools (doxygen, etc.) however I want something specific to Android which would pick the visual elements from the res folder and generate appropriate diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Class Visualizer](http://www.objectaid.com/) if you're using eclipqe :

> The ObjectAid UML Explorer is an agile and lightweight code visualization tool for the Eclipse IDE. It shows your Java source code and libraries in live UML class and sequence diagrams that automatically update as your code changes. The image below is a class diagram of actual source code; click on it to see the editor in the Eclipse Java Perspective.

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Paradigm** could be helpful for you.

Type Ctrl+Alt+S (or go to Preferences), then go to the Plugins tab, press "Browse repositories" button then search

**Visual Paradigm SDE** *for IntellIJ (Community edition)*

You need to install proper software from http://www.visual-paradigm.com/sdeij.php Now it should works well.

I guess that UML Class Diagram is only available on Ultimate Edition.

For more detail check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17137639/1276495)