# Generate State machine diagram from android code

Tags: android, state-machine

I want to draw state machine diagram of an android code automatically, Is there any plug in for android studio to doing so? Or other solution using enterprise architect?

I see questions about UML diagrams but i didn't find any solution for drawing state machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio

Comment: That question is about class diagram, and SimpleUMLCE plugin only provide class diagram, dependency diagram, package diagram and sequence diagram.

Answer (score 1):

My Kotlin state machine library has an export feature to PlantUML. It is not integrated with Android Studio, but it is easy to visualize state machine structure in online editor http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/

https://github.com/nsk90/kstatemachine