# Is there any way to generate sequence diagram from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, uml, sequence-diagram

I have created sample android project. Now i have to create sequence diagram for that. Is there any way to automatically generate sequence diagram for android project from android studio.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally I  got the solution.

I have installed a plugin, previously called `SequencePluginReload` from Android Studio, now called [SequenceDiagram](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8286-sequencediagram)

It is very easy to use and works like charm.

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me like a charm

Comment: Where is it generated? I mean to which path?

Answer (score 10):

I have downloaded [SequenceDiagram](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8286-sequencediagram) suggested by @venkatesh in above answer, but didn't understand how to use it. After  searching I found how to use it.

1. Download the zip file in the above link.
2. Go to Android Studio>Preferences in Mac. For Windows File>Settings.
3. Search for Plugins in search box. Then in right click on 'install plugin 
   from disk'. Browse for the downloaded zip and select it, then Apply and 
   it will show icon to restart android studio. Do it.
4. Now go to any method in your java file and right click on it and click on 'Sequence Diagram'. And you will find your diagram in a tab besides Debug,Terminal, version control etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hard to get a sequence diagram. But we can generate a class diagram from Android Studio. We need to install an external plug-in.

Following this references below:
[How to generate Class Diagram (UML) on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio)