# How to generated UML Diagram to Android Studio 2.2?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to generate UML diagram Android Studio 2.2 ?

I search plugins, are not found plugins SimpleUMLCE and forever...

I use [How to generate Class Diagram (UML) on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio/36823007#36823007) ... dont help.

Any information ?

[Plugins [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRAMc.png)

And my Version Android Studio: 
[Version Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m53oP.png)

Comment: SimpleUMLCE is not compatible with latest versions. Here is link to try out: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4946-simpleumlce

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I am searching for the same...