# How to generate UML diagram on Android studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, uml, class-diagram, android-studio-2.2

I've tried the solutions presented in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio), but I don't have the plugin mentioned, and none of the suggested methods to generate UML work.

Since the post is 4 years old, things might have changed but I can't seem to find any solutions. Does anyone know how to generate UML in Android studio 2.2 (the latest version of android, can't remember the version name).

Thanks.

Comment: Try this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/36823007/1245894](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36823007/1245894)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find SImpleUMLCE plugin in Android Studio but you can download from jetbrains and install in your Android Studio.

**1.** Go to jetbrains website and download the plugin:  plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4946-simpleumlce – htzfun

**2.** Open Android Studio and go to Android Studio>>Preferences(on MAC)>>Plugins
Now, you have to click on **Install plugin from disk...**[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EilXb.png)

**3.** Search the file you have downloaded in the first step and that's all