# How to generate UML diagram with components and classes in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to create a UML diagram from a package which contains packages. The problem is that when I click `Java Class Diagrams` on the `SRP` package the UML generated shows me the packages names only and not the classes inside them or the dependencies between those packages.

[image]

Is it possible to generate a UML diagram that contains all the classes for the `SRP` package and the dependencies between them?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio-intellij-idea/36823007#36823007

Comment: It seems that it is doable with plugins, that's unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem today, I know this question is 2 years ago, but you can show classes inside a package by **right click => Expand Nodes (E)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the package in the diagram and click "Show Dependencies".

Hope you find this useful. Have a lovely day !

Comment: The dependencies between the packages can be displayed as you used but I want to show all the classes of the `SRP` classes in one UML diagram.