# How to create an UML diagram in Android Studio - JAVA via sofrware

Tags: java, android-studio, uml, tool-uml

so i have a big Android Studio Java project and i need to write an UML.
Because the project is big i would love to get an add on / software who will do it for me =)

tnx! =)

Answer (score -1):

This answer shows you how to download the plugin and how to use it. Hope it's what you are looking for.
[How to generate Class Diagram (UML) on Android Studio (IntelliJ Idea)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio-intellij-idea/36823007#36823007)

Comment: SimpleUML hasn't been updated in years, and is marked as incompatible with current versions of anything, for anyone finding this answer in the future.